# How to bind super-c and super-v to copy and paste in gnome-terminal?

Tags: gnome, keyboard, shortcut-keys, gnome-terminal

I want to use <kbd>Super</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> instead of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> for gnome terminal copy and paste. I've set this up in Preferences -> Shortcuts, but it doesn't seem to work.

Other <kbd>Super</kbd> shortcuts like <kbd>Super</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> for new tab work correctly.

Anyone know how to fix this?

Screenshot of my Preferences window:

[image]

Comment: allow us to edit your questions to amend for images upload instead of put links. image will help to easy get the question.

Comment: They open Search photos / Search videos for me. Did you remove these bindings somehow? (I couldn't quickly find how to.) If so, how? Are these keycombos perhaps still caught by someone before hitting gnome-terminal?

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve using **xmodmap** commands:

```
remove mod4 = Super_L
keysym Super_L = Control_L
add Control = Control_L
```

Save the above lines as `super_as_ctrl.xmodmap`. Test by executing

```
xmodmap super_as_ctrl.xmodmap
```

To make the change permanent (surviving re-login/reboot) just rename the file to `.Xmodmap` in your home folder.

(Tested on Ubuntu 14.x live system)

PS: You could also make use of other windows button. Not sure how to do that.

Comment: Doesn't work for Ubuntu 22.04 LTS, I get the following error:
"xmodmap:  super_as_ctrl.xmodmap:1:  bad keysym in remove modifier list 'Super_L', no corresponding keycodes
xmodmap:  super_as_ctrl.xmodmap:2:  bad keysym target keysym 'Super_L', no corresponding keycodes
xmodmap:  2 errors encountered, aborting."